# Pass control to new WinForm c#

Tags: c#, winforms, search

Is there any way to pass controls to a winForm actually what I want to do is a search form, this form will be requested from different forms and the content of this form will be dynamical I though I can pass proper controls to my form  but can't think of the implemetation

Comment: Maybe you could create the "search form" as a user control which can be easily implemented as a control on any form you wish.

Comment: Why would you want to pass different controls? You can pass some integer (enum) argument to the Form's constructor from which you can decide which controls to dynamically add to the form.

Comment: You can't add controls from other forms anyway so this approach is a dead end. Build several Panels in the search form, each with possible set of controls, and decide which of them to show based on argument passed to the search form constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the controls you want to pass to the form are really dynamic you can pass them to the constructor of the form and add them to its control collection.

```
class SearchForm
{
    public void SearchForm(IEnumerable<Control> contentControls)
    {
        foreach(var contentControl in contentControls)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(contentControl);
        }
    }    
}
```

If however you want only want the client of the form to be able to show only a subset of some predefined controls you are better of passing some enum to the constructor and based on its value creating the appropriate controls.

```
enum SearchControls
{
    None = 0,
    Search = 1,
    Replace = 1 << 2,
    RecentSearches= 1 << 3,
}

class SearchForm
{
    public void SearchForm(SearchControls searchControls)
    {
        if(searchControls.HasFlag(SearchControls.Search))
            CreateAndAddSearchControl();   
        if(searchControls.HasFlag(SearchControls.Replace))
            CreateAndAddReplaceControl();
        if(searchControls.HasFlag(SearchControls.RecentSearches))
            CreateAndAddRecentSearchesControl();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass controls, although the convention with Windows Forms is to assign properties, instead of using constructor parameters.

```
// Control holding the search form
public class MySearchControl : UserControl {    ...   }

// Form to read data from the search form
public class MyFormForReadingSearchControl : Form
{    
   // Constructor is as normal

   public MySearchControl SearchControl { get; set; } 
}

// Form to send the search data.
public class MyForForSendingTheSearchControl : Form
{    
   public MySearchControl SearchControl { get; set; }

   protected void searchControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
   {
      var newForm = new MyFormForReadingSearchControl();
      newForm.SearchControl = this.SearchControl; // Pass via property
      newForm.Show();    
   }
}
```

For `SearchControl`, create derived classes of the various search forms that you require. Define some standard properties or methods to retrieve the data in a generic way.